# Haskell: Could not find module `Data.List.Split'

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to split a list in Haskell. As to my knowledge, the easiest way to do this is with `splitOn`, but this function requires `Data.List.Split`, so I tried to run `import Data.List.Split` in Prelude. However, I got the following error:

`Could not find module Data.List.Split`

Simply importing `Data.List` does work, however.

What could I do to solve this? Or, even better: is there an easy, built-in alternative to split lists?

Comment: What do you want to split the list on? Is it, by any chance, a `String` you want to split on `'\n'` or `\s+`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer. I would like to split a `String` on whitespaces.

Comment: You do know about cabal or stack, right? — BTW, it's also quite easy to split lists with tools from `base` only...

Comment: @Algorithm_NL: Then this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You were actually trying to split a string, but asked about your (non-working) solution.

Comment: @Zeta Wow, I didn't realize that. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To split a `String` on arbitrary white space (e.g. any Char `c` where `Data.Char.isSpace c` is `True`), use `words`:

```
-- words :: String -> [String]
ghci> words "Hello World, I'm a string \n example   \r\t with white space"
["Hello","World,","I'm","a","string","example","with","white","space"]
```

No need for additional imports, since [`words`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) is part of the `Prelude`.

Comment: How do you split on a given string that is not necessarily whitespace? For example when reading a csv file.

Comment: @user3224967 CSV is a lot more complicate than that, since `"` breaks delimiter, e.g. `Mayer;John;"Department of StackOverflow; Washington"` is a record with three, not four fields.

Answer (score 13):

`Data.List.Split` is not in the [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) I think you'll have to install [`split`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split)

### Update

after the clarification in the comments that only splitting on whitespace is required - use `words`/`lines` to your need - see also @Zeta's answer.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Would there be any way to do this without installing packages?

Comment: but I think it is in the haskell plattform - since ghc-7.8, and even though it is not "safe" for small projects using ghc-7.6 I just copy paste the code in some module to not depend on the whole `split` package

Comment: if you add a `split == 0.2.2` to your `build-depends:`-statements it is quite simple to install the package - why would you like to avoid it?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: Maybe he doesn't even use a `.cabal` or `.yaml` file and only wants to write a stand-alone Haskell script for `runhaskell`.

Comment: sometimes I don't think about the obvious use-cases

Comment: @AlgorithmNL, you can generally copy the source code of the bits you need. Different packages on Hackage have different licenses, but they're all open source.